# Python pandas combinations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am relatively new to Pandas. 
How do I create a Dataframe in Pandas with the following output?

The possible values for each columns are True or False. I want to get all all possible combination of rows.

```
Col1  Col2  col3  col4
True  True  True  True
True  True  True  False
True  True  False True
True  True  False False
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `product` from `itertools`

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

N = 4
pd.DataFrame(product([True, False], repeat=N),
             columns=[f'Col{n+1}' for n in range(N)])
```

---

```
     Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0    True   True   True   True
1    True   True   True  False
2    True   True  False   True
3    True   True  False  False
4    True  False   True   True
5    True  False   True  False
6    True  False  False   True
7    True  False  False  False
8   False   True   True   True
9   False   True   True  False
10  False   True  False   True
11  False   True  False  False
12  False  False   True   True
13  False  False   True  False
14  False  False  False   True
15  False  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[True, False],[True, False],[True, False], [True, False]])\
  .to_frame()\
  .reset_index(drop=True)\
  .set_axis(['col1','col2','col3','col4'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

Output:

```
     col1   col2   col3   col4
0    True   True   True   True
1    True   True   True  False
2    True   True  False   True
3    True   True  False  False
4    True  False   True   True
5    True  False   True  False
6    True  False  False   True
7    True  False  False  False
8   False   True   True   True
9   False   True   True  False
10  False   True  False   True
11  False   True  False  False
12  False  False   True   True
13  False  False   True  False
14  False  False  False   True
15  False  False  False  False
```